# React Router active Class for home page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-component

I've got a navigation that I am having a hard time trying to style. I have been able to add active classes to the navigational elements and apply styles to them, however the main dashboard which functions as a homepage does not get the dedicated active class applied to it when I click it. After doing a little bit of digging around in the app, I believe the AppRouter.js or routeConfig.js might be the issue.

The navigational elements are displayed with the Navlink code below:

```
  renderNavigationItem = (navigationItem) => {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { id, name, parentUrlLink } = navigationItem;
    return (
      <NavLink exact key={id.toString()} to={{ pathname: parentUrlLink }} className="desk-link" 
      activeClassName='is-active'>
        <MenuItem className={classes.fontBoldHeader}>{name}</MenuItem>
      </NavLink>
    );
  }
```

The app router looks like this:

```
class AppRouter extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
    this.context = context;
  }

  render() {
    const { account } = this.context;
    return (
      <Switch>
        {account ? <Redirect exact from="/" to={{ pathname: '/dashboard' }} /> : <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />}
        {routes.map((item) => <PrivateRoute {...item} key={`${item.path}-route`} />)}
        <Route path="/sessiontimeout" render={(props) => <TimedOutPage {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/500" render={(props) => <Error errorCode="500" {...props} />} />
        <Route path="/503" render={(props) => <Error errorCode="503" {...props} />} />
        <Route path="*" render={(props) => <Error errorCode="404" {...props} />} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

It looks like there's a specific rule that is in place for the "dashboard" page. It is also the page people go to if they click the logo so I feel like there is a specific rule that is preventing the dashboard page to inherit the "is-active" class. I am new to React so this is something that is a little over my head at the moment and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Here is where rednerNavigation is called:

```
renderNavigation = () => {
    const { menuNavigation } = this.props;
    return menuNavigation.map((item) => {
      if (item.children.length > 0) {
        return this.renderNavigationItemWithSubNav(item);
      }
      return this.renderNavigationItem(item);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Is your homepage is also a Navlink ?

Comment: Can you please show where you use `renderNavigationItem` ?

Comment: @vishnusandhireddy I would assume so. I don't see code anywhere stating otherwise

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer See the edited question. Thanks!